# Static lifetime requirements for managed state

Tags: rust, lifetime, rust-rocket

I'm having troubles with a managed `State` with `Rocket`. This state holds a Database connection and a collection of Cursors on that Database. Each one of theses have a reference on the  Database.

One of the operations on that state require to create a new cursor on the Database and keep it for later use. Unfortunatly, I am stuck with a lifetime problem. Usually, I have no problem dealing with thoses, but right now, I'm out of ideas...

I have recreated the problem bellow in a short example.

```rust
#![feature(proc_macro_hygiene, decl_macro)]
#[macro_use]
extern crate rocket;

use rocket::State;

struct Database;

impl Database {
    fn create_cursor(&self) -> Cursor {
        Cursor { database: self }
    }
}

struct Cursor<'a> {
    database: &'a Database
}

struct Controller<'a> {
    database: Database,
    cursors: Vec<Cursor<'a>>,
}

impl<'a> Controller<'a> {
    fn do_work(&'a mut self) {
        let cursor = self.database.create_cursor();
        self.cursors.push(cursor)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let database = Database;
    let controller = Controller { database, cursors: Vec::new() };

    rocket::ignite()
        .manage(controller)
        .launch();
}

#[get("/")]
pub fn do_work_route(
    mut controller: State<'static, Controller<'static>>
) -> &'static str {
    controller.do_work();
    "Something..."
}
```

```
error[E0621]: explicit lifetime required in the type of `__req`
  --> src/main.rs:42:9
   |
40 | #[get("/")]
   | ----------- help: add explicit lifetime `'static` to the type of `__req`: `&'_b rocket::Request<'static>`
41 | pub fn do_work_route(
42 |     mut controller: State<'static, Controller<'static>>
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^ lifetime `'static` required
```

Any lead would be appreciated. Meanwhile, I'll continue digging.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Controller` struct as written is self-referential, which is not possible: https://users.rust-lang.org/t/how-to-write-software-without-self-referential-structs/13819

The reason is that when a `Controller` gets moved, the references to the database in its `cursors` member would become invalid, because the memory location of its `database` member changed.

The best way forward is probably to step back and think about a design that is not self-referential. A possible solution is to make the database a [static variable](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/static-items.html), then your cursors could store `&'static Database` references.

If that fails, the link above mentions the [rental](https://docs.rs/rental/0.5.4/rental/) crate, but it doesn't seem to be easy to use.

Comment: That's the lead I wanted. I *kinda* knew something was wrong there, but now I have confirmation. Also, by knowing the problem name (Self-Referential Structs), I can do some more research. Thank you.